# How to use Google Indexing API to have Google Bot crawl my pages instantly

Tags: google-search-console, google-search, googlebot

I recently came across a few articles that said that using the Google Indexing API will make Google Bot instantly crawl and index all my website's pages. As I have a large number of pages on my site, it would help it tremendously as the normal Google Bot is only crawling about 500 pages a day.

I was wondering if using this API would really make Google Bot crawl all my pages instantly and have them show up on Google Search as an alternative to using a sitemap? Also, I heard from a friend that using the Google Custom Search API on my site would automatically make Google Bot crawl my site also. Is this true?

Comment: Can you share these articles you came across?   I don't know of any "indexing API" from Google.

Comment: Hi! I came across these articles: https://rankmath.com/blog/google-indexing-api/    https://medium.com/@WillmannTobias/google-indexing-api-tests-with-normal-urls-which-have-neither-job-posting-nor-livestream-4fa8af85c950

Comment: Does your site constantly create and delete many short-lived pages that contain job postings, broadcast events, or video objects?

Comment: We do have some short-lived pages but none that fit into those criteria

Answer (score 2):

This is a very common misconception actually. The indexing API only works for job postings or livestream videos.

"Currently, the Indexing API can only be used to crawl pages with either JobPosting or BroadcastEvent embedded in a VideoObject. For websites with many short-lived pages like job postings or livestream videos, the Indexing API keeps content fresh in search results because it allows updates to be pushed individually."
https://developers.google.com/search/apis/indexing-api/v3/quickstart

However, you may want to look into Bing's Indexing API, which does what you describe. https://www.bing.com/webmasters/url-submission-api